# mysql count mcgross based on condition

Tags: mysql

```
Select p.item_name,
  sum(p.mc_gross Case when u.ag_code!=0),
  Sum(p.mc_gross Case when u.ag_code=0)                                
From table1 as p,table2 as u
Where p.payment_status = 'success'
Group By p.item_name
```

This query have error

mcgross,ag_code,cdate,mdate,item_name is the column names in my table

My result want like this

```
item_name   sum1    Sum2
Bronze  11.71   9.99
Silver  35.82   540.88
Enterprise  145.3   308.94
Silver  156.94  1
Bronze  451.86  7.99
Gold    565.56  1019.74
Enterprise  671.17  608.88
Gold    71.23   38.99
```

Comment: issue fixed thanks

SELECT p.item_name, Sum(
CASE WHEN u.ag_code !=0
THEN p.mc_gross
END ) AS dircus, Sum(
CASE WHEN u.ag_code =0
THEN p.mc_gross
END ) AS agent, p.cdate AS filter, p.mdate
FROM table1 AS p, table2 AS u
WHERE p.payment_status = 'success'
GROUP BY p.user_id
LIMIT 0 , 30

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without more info but try chaning it to `group by Item_name`.